# JDBC driver not found inside tomcat docker image

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker, tomcat

I have a spring framework web application and I'm trying to deploy it into production using tomcat with docker image.

I searched about this error and found out there are two possible errors. The first one is incorrect database url format and I check mine and it's correct. The database url is like this

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=volga&stringtype=unspecified
```

The second possible problem is the Postgres db library file is not included in war file. So I run bash command inside the running tomcat container and check for Postgres library file and it exists in the war file. I also tried to copy the Postgres library into tomcat lib folder and it's not working.

I create a repo with minimum code to reproduce the error.
https://github.com/ap30422/spring-boot.git

Please clone the repo and change directory to `compete` directory.
Run `mvn clean install package` to build the app.
Then run `Docker build .` to build the image.
Run Docker image with `docker run #insert_image_id. -p 8080:8080`

If you check http://localhost:8080, you will see the `Down` text and the error log in the docker container log.

Comment: **check for oracle library file** You are using Postgresql **not** Oracle. Including the oracle drivers and expect that to work with Postgresql is wrong. The sample you link to doesn't have any JDBC driver included. Next to that it is wrong, Tomcat 8.x won't even work with Spring Boot 3.x next to that don't deploy to tomcat just run the application (tomcat is included already).

Comment: It was typo error I forgot to change the name. Currently I'm testing only with Postgres to simply things in my test repo.  The repo uses Spring Boot 1.5.  I just updated the pom.xml file. Maybe you didn't look carefully.

Comment: Trust me I did, it extended the parent 3.1 and used Tomcat 8.5 in the dockerfile. At least the gradle file did. What you also didn't tell is that you are totally not using Spring Boot when doing JDBC stuff. It will **not** load the driver automatically you need first to do `Class.forName(<driver class here>)`. You are making things very complicated in your sample and have more work working around and not using the frameworks you choose then when you would just use them.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'm using the ``mvn`` to build the project. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What you also didn't tell is that you are totally not using Spring Boot when doing JDBC stuff. It will not load the driver automatically you need first to do `Class.forName(<driver class here>)`. You are making things very complicated in your sample and have more work working around and not using the frameworks you choose then when you would just use them. (I added that to my previous comment while you were commenting as well).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying very hard to work around all the things that Spring Boot offers.

1. You don't use the auto-configured `DataSource` but try to do things yourself.
2. You aren't using the embedded Tomcat but instead try to deploy the application.

Use the frameworks and tools you have to there advantage instead of working around things.

## Use the Spring Boot `DataSource`

In your `application.properties` (should be in `src/main/resources`) add the following

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=volga&stringtype=unspecified
spring.datasource.username=ni
spring.datasource.password=ni
```

Next modify your `HelloController` to use a `DataSource` or even better a `JdbcTemplate`.

```java
@RestController
public class HelloController {

  private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

  public HelloController(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
    this.jdbc=jdbc;
  }

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String index() {
  
    try {
      String hello = jdbc.queryForObject("select 'hello'", String.class);
      return "UP";
    } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
      return "DOWN";
    }
  }
}
```

Now you are properly using the Spring Boot configured `DataSource` and Spring Boot will load the correct driver (if it is on the classpath).

The application will probably fail to start as I doubt that in the container you are building for this application there is a PostgreSQL database available.

## Use embedded tomcat

Spring Boot already provides Tomcat as the default provider and should be used to run it. Change your applicatation to a `jar` and not a `war`. And modify your `Dockerfile` to launch the application instead of using Tomcat and deploy the application.

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:8-jre-alpine
ADD target/*.jar /app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This will just launch the application you have created and utilize the embedded tomcat instance.

**NOTE:** This is not the best Dockerfile for a Spring Boot application, you want to use more layers so you can enable reuse. See the [Spring Boot Docker Guide](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/).

Answer (score -1):

The current issue you're encountering may be attributed to either the absence of JDBC drivers or misconfigurations in your Spring Boot application or Tomcat Docker image. Here are a few steps you can follow to address and potentially resolve the problem:

**1. Verify Dependency Management.**

Confirm that the PostgreSQL JDBC driver is included in your pom.xml file as a dependency. If it's not already there, add the following lines

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>your_postgresql_version</version>
</dependency>
```

**2. Check the Classpath in Spring Boot.**

While Spring Boot should automatically load the JDBC driver into the classpath, you can explicitly specify the driver class in either the application.properties or application.yml file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

**3. Verify Database Connection URL**

Ensure that the database connection URL is correct. If the database is on a different server, use the appropriate hostname or IP address. Also, confirm that Tomcat can resolve "localhost" if that's part of the URL.

**4. Docker Image Build**

When creating the Docker image, make sure to copy the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to the correct location within the image. For instance, you can copy it to a "lib" folder. Modify your Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM tomcat:latest
COPY target/spring-boot.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY target/dependency/*.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/
```

By following these steps, you should be able to address potential issues related to JDBC drivers and configurations in your Spring Boot application and Tomcat Docker image.

Comment: I followed your suggested steps but still not working.
1.  I already had the dependency for postgres. 
``<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.2.2</version>
  </dependency>``
2. I don't have classpath config in my spring boot. Maybe you can help me how to setup the application.yml
3.  I used the different url from repo which is accessible from docker container.
4. I copied the lib files like you mentioned above and files are in container.
Thank you for your suggestion. Seem like I have to try dig more deeper.

Comment: He doesn't "use" Spring Boot but works around it, which is the cause of the issue.